# Use onFormSubmit on a sheet to log each form edit

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a form that stores responses on a sheet. The form is set to allow edits.
I need to track each time a user updates their version/copy of the form.
I've tried the following code. I noticed that e.values only seems to contain the new updated values (and the timestamp). I need the 2nd column to also contain the "Forum Name" (column B) value, even if it hasn't updated.

```
  function copyUpdate(e) {
  // triggered onFormSubmit
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Log");

  // force the 2nd column to always contain "Forum Name" value
  var newValues = e.values;
  newValues[1] = e.namedValues["Forum Name"][0];
  // Output the timestamp, Forum Name & any changed values
  sheet.appendRow(newValues);
}
```

I'm probably making a really basic mistake, but I'm just not seeing it.

Any help would be most appreciated

Be Well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, e.namedValues also only contains the new edited values.

I had to search the other sheet for a row that matched the timestamp, and then copy that row to the new sheet. :(

TTFN